# Webpack + React: pass commit SHA from webpack to JS

Tags: javascript, git, reactjs, webpack, commit

I'm using webpack (V 1.13.2) to bundle my webapp + ReactJS.

**I'd like to pass the current commit SHA to the js.**

Getting the current commit SHA is [straightforward](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35150186/getting-git-revision-hash-with-webpack), but I couldn't figure out how to pass it the to js file.
I tried to change the output js file and chain the commit SHA to it:

```
output:{
        path: distPath,
        publicPath: '/',
        filename: "client.min.js?" + COMMIT_SHA
      },
```

But the webpack won't bundle it.

I also tried to use [string-replace-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/string-replace-loader) like the following:

```
webpack.config.js:
{
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        loader: 'string-replace-loader',
        query: {
          search: 'COMMIT_SHA_ANCHOR',
          replace:  VERSION
        }
      },
```

client.js:

```
var commit = 'COMMIT_SHA_ANCHOR';
```

but I get a syntax error (it creates a new line before closing the string):

```
Unterminated string constant (34:13)

var commit = '4820fa5de22d3463a0ca39c1d4067a62800d1d07
     |              ^
  35 | ';
```

What is the best way (if exists) to pass the commit SHA to js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`DefinePlugin`](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/define-plugin/) should do what you want.

In your `webpack.config.js`:

```
plugins: [
  new webpack.DefinePlugin({COMMIT_SHA: JSON.stringify(VERSION)})
]
```

This will create a global variable `COMMIT_SHA` that you can refer to anywhere:

```
console.log(COMMIT_SHA);
```

---

You should also verify that the `VERSION` string you're using doesn't already contain the newline at the end. Try adding `console.log(JSON.stringify(VERSION))` to your webpack config and see if it includes `\n`.

Comment: The VERSION string indeed has a newline char. 
I removed it with 'VERSION.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm,"");' and it worked.